# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arulesViz’: object ‘cividis’ is not exported by 'namespace:viridisLite'

Tags: r

In R 3.4.3 (Windows 10) while loading the packages arulesViz:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arulesViz’: object ‘cividis’ is not exported by 'namespace:viridisLite'

I tried to uninstall and install, but did not help. What is wrong and how can i correct it?

Comment: small correction , this error is while loading the packages arulesViz. It is installed properly ,MD5 sum checked.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to install the dependencies of arulesViz.
I tried with Scatterplot3d , viznetwork, vcd, virdislite.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problem.
This problem can be resolved by installing package "viridisLite" along with "arulesViz"
for me it worked no need to reinstallthe R or Rstudio

Answer (score 0):

It get solved , after reinstall RStudio + removed old version of R.
Disadvantage is all libraries will also get removed. So you have to load again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the seriation package. Ultimately I found that I just had to uninstall and reinstall r and r studio. Then i ran update.packages() and I had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain, as there are several packages with dependencies for packages which in turn import `viridisLite`, and this error is very opaque for users...

One thing I've found works (apart from manually `install.packages("")` each package mentioned in the error) is to switch repositories to the RStudio-maintained Cloud repo. (repo 0).

The problem seems to have hit people with a default repo that has incompatible versions of packages at the time people use it, and the cloud repo seems to avoid/not suffer from this problem.

Hope this helps